# How can I see my files in 2nd partition of hdd?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, format

I'm a new Ubuntu user. I installed Ubuntu on my computer yesterday.

I choose my 2nd partition of hdd's mount point as /home and format type ext4.

Now, I can't see my 2nd partition or can't change format type the only thing I can do is choosing flag type from gparted. Do you have any idea how can i use it?

Comment: Please open a terminal, go to the dash, type terminal. When it's open type: 'df' and put here the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use gparted to change a partition that is mounted. You say you cant see your 2nd partition but if it is mounted to /home then everything in this folder will be on your 2nd partition.

If you open the 'System Monitor' and click the 'File Systems' tab you will be able to see each partition and where it is mounted.

If you would like to alter a partition then you will have to do so from a live USB or CD as this it the only way you will be able to change the HD without mounting it first.

Comment: /dev/sdb1             24607172   5717096  17640076  25% /
udev                   1018640        12   1018628   1% /dev
tmpfs                   411024       964    410060   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                   1027552       260   1027292   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb6            127165204   2565668 118139888   3% /home

this is the output

Answer (score 0):

Linux differs from Windows in that it incorporates the various partitions "invisibly" into your directory structure, whereas Windows lists them as various drives. So what this means for you, is that /home is your other partition, whereas the rest of your file system is mounted on your first partition. 
Try running "df -h" , it will give the output to you in a form that will be easier to read.

Comment: thanks to all answers i solved it by installing ubuntu again